# Determine required Ada source files for project build

Tags: ada, gnat, gprbuild

Imagine a large Ada project build with GPRbuild and a single `*.gpr` project file. The source directory contains many Ada package specification and body files but a few of them are not required to build the project (an executable).

Does GPRbuild offers something like a report function listing all files that were required to the build the project? This would allow me to remove unusued source files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play around with

> -gnatu    List units for this compilation

like this:

```
gprbuild -P foo.gpr -cargs -gnatu
```